# WPF C# Changing label content in code here doesn't reflect

Tags: c#, wpf, label

I have a `Label` here in XAML. If I set the content in the XAML side, it will display. But when I try to set the content in code behind, it doesn't display as it shows:

My code:

```
if (Application.Current.Resources["Values"] != null)
{
    string score = Application.Current.Resources["Values"].ToString();
    labelscore.Content = score;           
}
```

I have checked the vale of the resource, the value is there but I can't display it.

My XAML side:

```
<Label Height="30" Width="100" Name="labelscore" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" />
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on `labelscore.Content = score;` in your code-behind to ensure that it's actually being called?

Comment: I think your problem is in the IF. you need as Chris Suggested to set a break point and check.

Comment: Have you defined about this resource in your Application.Resources Tag inside App.xaml..??

Answer (score 0):

Try temporarily changing your line of code to

```
labelscore.Content = "TEST STRING";
```

and comment out the following line

```
if (Application.Current.Resources["Values"] != null)
```

If the `Label` displays the text, then your `Resources` are the problem.

Alternatively, try binding the value from your code behind to the `Label`. This is generally the preferred method when using WPF.

```
<Label Height="30" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Values}" ... />
```